# Why acquireUninterruptibly() method of Semaphore class in java is not working as expected?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore, java.util.concurrent

I have two Java files:

Check.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
class Check
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  Semaphore s = new Semaphore(1);
  MyThread t1 = new MyThread("t1",s);
  MyThread t2 = new MyThread("t2",s);
  t1.start();
  t2.start();
  t2.interrupt();
 }
}
```

MyThread.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
class MyThread extends Thread
{
 Semaphore s;
 MyThread(String name, Semaphore s)
 {
  super(name);
  this.s=s;
 }
 public void run()
 {
  try
  {
        s.acquireUninterruptibly();
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"-"+i);
        }
        s.release();
  }
  catch(InterruptedException e){}
 }
}
```

If I comment out the statement "t2.interrupt()" then both the threads are executing fine. But if I do not comment the statement then the thread t2 is not executing at all. According to my understanding of acquireUninterruptibly() method the thread t2 should keep on waiting for permit even after getting an interrupt. Then why does the thread t2 stop working after getting an interrupt?

Comment: @ScaryWombat If not then both the threads should execute. Why only the thread t1 is executing if the statement "t2.interrupt()" is used?

Comment: @ScaryWombat it doesn’t matter whether `t2` is interrupted before, in-between, or after the invocation of `s.acquireUninterruptibly()`, as long as it is interrupted after main’s call of `t2.start()` and before the completion of its first `sleep` call, as up to this point, it didn’t perform any perceivable action and therefore, the resulting behavior will always be the same.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you should not catch exceptions and ignore them. Further, you should not place exception handlers in a way, that the code will miss the critical `release()` call in the exceptional case. Generally, minimizing the protected code area can help tracking down issues.

When you change the code to

```
Semaphore s = new Semaphore(1);
Runnable r = () -> {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" - before acquire");
    s.acquireUninterruptibly();
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" - acquired");
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" - "+e);
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" - "+i);
    }
    s.release();
};
Thread t1 = new Thread(r, "t1");
Thread t2 = new Thread(r, "t2");
t1.start();
t2.start();
t2.interrupt();
```

You’ll get

```
t1 - before acquire
t2 - before acquire
t1 - acquired
t1 - 0
t1 - 1
t1 - 2
t1 - 3
t1 - 4
t2 - acquired
t2 - java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
t2 - 0
t2 - 1
t2 - 2
t2 - 3
t2 - 4
```

in most cases. This is not guaranteed, as it is possible that `t2` acquires the semaphore first.

For the typical timing, `t1` acquires first and `t2` gets interrupted before or while executing `acquireUninterruptibly()`. But it doesn’t matter whether `t2` is interrupted before, in-between, or after the invocation of `acquireUninterruptibly()`, as this method ignores the interruption. Therefore, the ⟨interrupted⟩ status persists until the thread performs the first action which does care for it.

In this example, it’s the first `sleep` call. In your code, this terminates the thread, as your `try … catch` statement covered the entire code. In my example, it covers only one `sleep` call and since this call will reset the ⟨interrupted⟩ status when reporting it via `InterruptedException`, the subsequent calls will sleep as intended after catching the exception.

You can also check and clear the status yourself, e.g.

```
Semaphore s = new Semaphore(1);
Runnable r = () -> {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" - before acquire");
    s.acquireUninterruptibly();
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" - acquired");
    if(Thread.interrupted())
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                          +" - interruption before or during acquire");
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" - "+e);
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" - "+i);
    }
    s.release();
};
Thread t1 = new Thread(r, "t1");
Thread t2 = new Thread(r, "t2");
t1.start();
t2.start();
t2.interrupt();
```

which may lead to

```
t1 - before acquire
t2 - before acquire
t1 - acquired
t1 - 0
t1 - 1
t1 - 2
t1 - 3
t1 - 4
t2 - acquired
t2 - interruption before or during acquire
t2 - 0
t2 - 1
t2 - 2
t2 - 3
t2 - 4
```

As said, it’s not guaranteed. Sometimes, it prints

```
t2 - before acquire
t1 - before acquire
t2 - acquired
t2 - interruption before or during acquire
t2 - 0
t2 - 1
t2 - 2
t2 - 3
t2 - 4
t1 - acquired
t1 - 0
t1 - 1
t1 - 2
t1 - 3
t1 - 4
```

instead.

Compare with the [documentation of `Semaphore.acquireUninterruptibly()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquireUninterruptibly--)

> If the current thread is interrupted while waiting for a permit then it will continue to wait, but the time at which the thread is assigned a permit may change compared to the time it would have received the permit had no interruption occurred. When the thread does return from this method its interrupt status will be set.

The last sentence is the crucial point. When the method is interrupted, it will continue to wait and return normally, but the thread’s “interrupt status will be set”, which will make the next interrupt-sensitive action react on it.

[In contrast, `Thread.sleep`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)):

> #### Throws:
>
> …
> `InterruptedException` - if any thread has interrupted the current thread. The *interrupted status* of the current thread is cleared when this exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Your second thread actually starts working BUT since you are ignoring `InterruptedException` (empty catch block for it) you cannot detect that your `interrupt()` call is executed while thread 2 is in sleep method. And that method throws `InterruptdeException` if interrupted. And due to that exception your thread 2 exits for-loop without printing anything.

This is what I see after adding `e.printStackTrace()` inside catch block.

> t1-0
>
> t1-1
>
> t1-2
>
> t1-3
>
> t1-4
>
> java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
>       at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
>       at MyThread.run(Parser.java:31)

Comment: I know the interrupt is working fine. But according to my understanding acquireUninterruptibly() method should keep on waiting for a permit even after getting an interrupt.

Comment: Yes, that fact is that you call `interrupt()` AFTER permit is acquired by t2 and it is inside `sleep()`. Unfortunately order of output in console may not be accurate in multithreaded program.

Comment: @mynameisGYAN JDK classes are tested very thoroughly so there is very little chance that a relatively old feature (and `Semaphore` was added in Java 1.5) is not working as described.

Comment: `interrupt()` doesn’t need to be called after the permit is acquired by `t2`. What matters, is that the `sleep` call is `t2`’s first action which reacts on it (as `acquireUninterruptibly()` ignores it). To say it explicitly, a thread’s interrupted status will persist until an action explicitly resets it, which `acquireUninterruptibly()` does not.

Comment: @Holger do you mean that `sleep()` checks interrupted flag once before doing actual sleep and after that also monitors that flag? JavaDoc doesn't exactly specify that: `if any thread has interrupted the current thread.` So I assume that `sleep()` will throw exception only when thread is interrupted while sleeping.

Comment: @Ivan you can easily check this [`Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); Thread.sleep(1);`](https://ideone.com/pZYyjw). This applies to all operations sensitive to interruption. As ordinary code between these actions is not affected and there’s no sense in making interruption dependent on the execution timing.

Comment: @Holger even if trivial, I had a huge WTF for that `sleep(1)`. what an excellent point!